# How do you use <p:poll/> tag without doing a full page refresh?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How do you use the `<p:poll/>` tag without doing a full page refresh?

I have this code below where I am telling the  tag to only update the messages id but it is updating the entire center layoutPane:

```
<pe:layoutPane id="center" position="center">
    <h:form id="mainF">
        <h:panelGroup id="centerContent" minHeight="70%" maxHeight="70%">
            <ui:include src="#{navigationBean.pageName}.xhtml" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
    <p:messages id="messages">  
        <p:effect type="pulsate" event="load" delay="1000">
            <f:param name="mode" value="'show'" />  
            <f:param name="times" value="1000" />
        </p:effect>
    </p:messages>
    <h:form id="pollF">
        <p:poll interval="10" listener="#{alarmsBean.checkAlarms()}" update=":messages" partialSubmit="true" process="pollF" />
    </h:form>
</pe:layoutPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:-

Change `<p:messages id="messages">` to

```
<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" showSummary="true">
```

**OR**

```
<p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true">
```

Comment: I actually tried partialSubmit like this and it seems that it is working:  `<p:poll interval="10" listener="#{alarmsBean.checkAlarms()}" update=":messages" partialSubmit="true" widgetVar="poll"/>`